# Simple parallel calculation with multiprocessing doesn't work

Tags: parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, python-3.6

I have a simple, yet very time-consuming, function with I want to parallelize to make it faster. This is Python 3.6 on a Jupyter Notebook. I do something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def func(x):
    return x**2
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
with Pool(5) as pool:
    results = pool.imap_unordered(func, y)
for r in results:
    print(r)
```

And the last statement runs forever and never ends.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You hit a problem with context scopes. Try moving `for r in results:` loop inside  `with` block:

```py
    with Pool(5) as pool:
        results = pool.imap_unordered(func, y)
        for r in results:
            print(r)
```

this works fine.

Alternatively, you could just use `Pool.map`

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def func(x):
    return x ** 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    with Pool(5) as pool:
        results = pool.map(func, y)
    for r in results:
        print(r)
```

which prints

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```